# Prevent Safari address bar from expanding in iOS 15

Tags: ios, safari

Currently in iOS 15 Beta 4. The app I'm working on involves dragging canvas elements around, and when I drag them up and down, the new floating address bar expands and collapses, which is undesirable. This was not an issue in iOS 14. How can this be prevented?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution yet? Our team is facing the same issue.

Comment: Well, by iOS 15 Beta 6 or 7 this behavior no longer happened. And now with the actual release of iOS 15, I don't see it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why. But this is only triggered if you use a < a > tag. If you trigger something from a DIV with JS instead it wont happen.